# Objective-c return data from asynchronous NSURLConnection - filling model class with data

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, model, nsurlconnection

what I want to achieve, is a class for parsing json. I know how to parse json and I've got nsurlconnection working through delegate.
The problem is, I want to make a method in that class, which will return a NSArray of those parsed elements from json.
What I have now:

```
@interface JSONParser : NSObject {
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSString *url;

    SBJsonParser *parser;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;

@end
```

and

```
@implementation JSONParser

@synthesize url;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
        url = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSArray *) parse {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self url]]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [request release];
    return ?;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

        NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //some parsing, filling the NSMutableArray
}
```

What I want to achieve is that parse method to somehow return the array generated through nsurlconnection. When it's generated I want to return it to the singleton model I've got created. 
Or is there any other/better approach for this?
I basically want to fill my model with data from json. But the problem is that I'll have a few different models and I can't just simply specify one to save into in the connectionDidFinishLoading method.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you look into something like SBJSON? http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Comment: Yup. No need to reinvent the wheel. Besides SBJson, there is the excellent and highly optimized JSONKit - https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Comment: Ok guys, you probably misunderstood me, I'm already using sbjson for parsing, that's the commented part I skipped, I just wanted to know how to return the parsed Array of my elements to the method that's creating the NSURLConnection, or how to return it somehow at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options for parsing the JSON data.  SBJSON was mentioned.  [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is another, very fast option.  It really is no more difficult than walking the NSArray and NSDictionary instances returned by the parser.

EDIT:
I see; you are wondering how to pass the results of an asynchronous process back to whatever object created that process. Why not use blocks for this?

Define a completion block for this:

```
typedef void(^myJSONReturnBlock)(NSArray *jsonObjs);
```

and an ivar for it in your parser class:

```
@interface MYParserClass : NSObject
{
    myJSONReturnBlock _completionHandler;
}
```

Then your `parse` method will be something like this:

```
- (void)parseWithCompletionHandler:(myJSONReturnBlock)aHandler;
{
    _completionHandler = Block_copy(aHandler);
    //  set up your asynchronous NSURLConnection here, etc
}
```

Now, your delegate methods will need to pass the array in this way:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
    //  parse data to array of objects
   if( _completionHandler )
        _completionHandler(yourNSArrayInstance);
}
```

Finally, your calling class will ask the parser to parse in this way:

```
[myParserClassInstance parseWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *jsonObjs)^{
    //  do something with the objects returned to you.
}];
```

Also, don't forget to `Block_release` your completion block ivar in your parser class in the `dealloc`

But if you don't want to deal with blocks, then just a delegate pattern in which your class holds a reference to the class to which you want to pass back the data.

Comment: OK, you are wondering how to pass the data back to the caller.  See edits about.  Use either blocks (my preferred solution) or implement your own delegate strategy.